# How to create a CSV file and save it to specific path on server?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to create a CSV file and save it to a specific path on the server. Here I used this code to create file, but it will directly open. I want to save it to a folder.

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv ');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
```

Comment: You don't need the `header` commands above if you are saving things to a file on the server.

Comment: but how can i save the csv file to folder?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). That will save a file to the server.

Comment: but how can i use it in my script??

Comment: @user3522975 By typing. Seriously, rtfm, I even gave you the link.

Comment: i know by typing :P but i jst know to create csv file using header script.. which i have used.. :(

Comment: @user3522975: be aware that programming does involve some problem solving and research - so if you get a useful link like the above one, read everything on the page, and be willing to try things! There are plenty of examples in the comments.